# Worksheet_change not working after multiple paste in the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'Excel VBA with more cells in the range.
    Dim lr As Integer

    lr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:AJ" & lr)) Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Target.row, 37).Value = "S"
    End If
End Sub
```

This code works fine if I try to modify cells one by one. But if I try pasting multiple values, only the first cell in the paste range gets the "S" value.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: you will need to loop the `Target` cells.  `Target.row` only returns the top row of the range.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'Excel VBA with more cells in the range.
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim lr As Long
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Me
        lr = .Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("B2:AJ" & lr)) Is Nothing Then
            Intersect(Target.EntireRow, .Columns(37)).Value = "S"
        End If
    End With
ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Note** I changed `Sheets("Sheet1")` to `Me` assuming it is the sheet you tracking the change in.

**Edit**: Added an error handler as suggested by @ScottCraner and implemented in @warcupine's answer.

Comment: The only thing I would add, is to have an error capture on like @warcupine, just in case it errors with the events turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Like Scott Craner said, you're referencing only the top cell when referring to a multicell range's row. Loop through them to get all the row numbers.

I added in disabling events, as that is a good idea when working in `worksheet_change` so you don't get stuck in a loop.

I also added in a check to see if there are blank values in the paste range and skip them.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'Excel VBA with more cells in the range.
    Dim lr As Long
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo eventexit
    lr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:AJ" & lr)) Is Nothing Then
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Range("B2:AJ" & lr))
            If Not cell.Value = "" Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(cell.Row, 37).Value = "S"
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
    
eventexit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```